# How to prepare training data for deep learning models

Tags: deep-learning, dataset, image-classification, training, image-preprocessing

I am working on a project which involves the application of deep learning models. I have collected training data. In collected images, I have **more than one object in interest**. I am not very clear how to label these images. Should I crop and then label or just feed as it is? I would appreciate any kind of help. In the attached image, I have marked two objects.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mask image with the background having value 0 and give all pixels the value of its class.

I am not sure what approach you are taking, but you can for example use Convolutional Neural Networks. They will learn from the mask image what features contribute to a pixel class and can therefore, at inference time, output a per pixel class probability.